# Assigns the reference instead of values in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, reference, drawing, line

I am making an application in silverlight.In that application i am using two dimensional array of line as

```
Line[][] Ecg=new Line[4][];
```

And in later part of application i am using code as

```
Line line=new Line();
line=Ecg[i][j];
line.Y1=line.Y1 + 100;
line.Y2=line.Y2 + 100;
//cod for drawing of line
```

Above my problem is that whenever i am increasing the value of Y1 and Y2 of object line, then it increments the value in Ecg array. I am not getting what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new new Line() object then throwing it away with the second line:

```
Line line=new Line();
line =...
```

You are then assigning a reference to a Line() object from the array:

```
line=Ecg[i][j]
```

If you then change a property of that Line object, it is the same object that is in the array.

You probably intended to copy the values from the object in the array instead?:

```
Line line=new Line()
    {
        X1= Ecg[i][j].X1, 
        X2= Ecg[i][j].X2, = Ecg[i][j].Y1, 
        Y2= Ecg[i][j].Y2 
    });
line.Y1=line.Y1 + 100;
line.Y2=line.Y2 + 100;
```

*This all seems a little odd though. What is the end result you are trying to get?*